# Why does this code say that C::f overrides A::f but not B::f?

Tags: c++

In [the 3rd code example here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual) the comment says that C::f overrides A::f. Why is this? My intuition says that it should override B::f.

```
struct A { virtual void f(); };     // A::f is virtual
struct B : A { void f(); };         // B::f overrides A::f in B
struct C : virtual B { void f(); }; // C::f overrides A::f in C
struct D : virtual B {}; // D does not introduce an overrider, B::f is final in D
struct E : C, D  {       // E does not introduce an overrider, C::f is final in E
    using A::f; // not a function declaration, just makes A::f visible to lookup
};
int main() {
   E e;
   e.f();    // virtual call calls C::f, the final overrider in e
   e.E::f(); // non-virtual call calls A::f, which is visible in E
}
```

Comment: I suggest adding some `cout` statements to see what is executed.

Answer (score 6):

Virtual Base classes are relevant only to data members, not methods.

It doesn't matter whether `C::f` overrides `A::f` or `B::f` - it's the same thing.

That comment could be changed to `C::f` overrides `B::f` and it would still mean the same thing.

Consider the following hierarchy (no virtual base classes)

```
class A { virtual void foo(); }
class B : public A { void foo(); }
class C : public B { void foo(); }
```

Here, `B::foo` overrides `A::foo`. `C::foo` overrides `B::foo`. So in effect, `C::foo` overrides `A::foo`.

Virtual base classes are used to avoid multiple base class instances - but that's relevant only to the data members in the base class not the methods. If a base class had only methods & no data members, there is no need to make it a virtual base class at all.

Answer (score 6):

The text of the C++14 standard is (class.virtual/2):

> If a virtual member function `vf` is declared in a class `Base` and in a class `Derived`, derived **directly or indirectly** from `Base`, a member function `vf` with the same name, parameter-type-list, cv-qualification, and ref-qualifier (or absence of same) as `Base::vf` is declared, then `Derived::vf` is also virtual (whether or not it is so declared) and it *overrides* `Base::vf`. For convenience we say that any virtual function overrides itself.

So `C::f` overrides all of `A::f`, `B::f` and `C::f`.

Comment: Here it says that it only overrides Base::vf. How do you conclude it overrides the other ones?

Comment: @LearningMath apply this quote to `Base = A, Derived = C` and also to `Base = B, Derived = C`.  And re-read the last sentence of the quote.  "derived indirectly" means that there could be a chain of class derivations.

Comment: Did you mean Base = A and Derived = B? Also, are you referring to the classes in the example given? If you want to explain a bit, I don't quite get you idea. Thanks a lot.

Comment: No, I mean what I said.  C is derived from B, therefore C::f overrides B::f.   C is derived indirectly from A, therefore C::f overrides A::f.

Comment: I get it now. Also, if it wasn't like this (if it only overrides A::f) I wouldn't be able to write b->f() where b is of class B and operates on an object of type C, right?

Comment: I guess you could say that, although it's moot since the concept of virtual functions wouldn't make sense if it didn't override B::f